# Image with Text in Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new to Windows Phone 8 application.

How can I write text on an image in Windows Phone 8? I would like, when the user clicks the top the text, to display the top of the image and when the user right clicks, for the text to display to the right side of the image. Is there any API for that ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a simple `Gird` structure. Place you `Image` and a `TextBlock` on the `Grid` and then move the `TextBlock` to where the user taps the control. You can even simplify that by using your `Image` as `Grid.BackgroundImage` and just have a `TextBlock` inside the Grid.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="...."/>
    </Grid.Background> 

   <!--
     place control inside Grid
   -->

</Grid>
```

Comment: Not fixed the control in design